# How to get a client side editor when working with MVC version of Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Well, I'm really stuck here. [This example by Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom) shows how to change a field when editing to whatever you need. Exactly,

```
columns: [
           { field: "Category", title: "Category", width: "180px", editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: "#=Category.CategoryName#" },
         ],
```

...where "categoryDropDownEditor" is a client side function that does the trick.

In MVC version there seems to be nothing of the kind. Is there? I keep believing that it should. I just do not need to traverse partial HTML from server each time I need to decorate an input field. And this is seemingly what "EditorTemplate", the only one available for MVC, does.

Answer (score 1):

OK. In case anyone will bump into the same. I ended up with this "too elegant" a solution:

```
.Events(e => e.Edit("editing"))
```

this line in grid initialization routine (server side) calls the named dynamic method (client side):

```js
function editing(e) {
        var input = e.container.find("input[name=Regex]");
        var textbox = $(document.createElement('textarea')).attr({
            id: input.id,
        }).width(input.width()).height(input.height()).val(input.val());
        input.hide();
        textbox.insertAfter(input);
        textbox.focus(function () {
            /*to make this flexible, I'm storing the current width & height in an attribute*/
            $(this).attr('data-defaultwidth', $(this).width());
            $(this).attr('data-defaultheight', $(this).height());
            $(this).animate({
                width: 400
            }, 'slow');
            $(this).animate({
                height: 300
            }, 'slow');
        }).blur(function () {
            /* lookup the original width */
            var w = $(this).attr('data-defaultwidth');
            var h = $(this).attr('data-defaultheight');
            $(this).animate({
                width: w
            }, 'slow');
            $(this).animate({
                height: h
            }, 'slow');
            input.val(textbox.val());
            input.trigger('change');
        });
    }
```

End tada, although it's a pure hack.